# Bracketing methods between bisection and regula falsi

Tags: sequences-and-series, numerical-methods, asymptotics, terminology, roots

Previous question, somewhat related: [Bracketing root-finding methods: my modified Illinois method](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3551775/272831).

I came up with another simple bracketing method that seems to work really well, especially against functions with initially poor secant approximations or multiple order roots.

We define:

- $[a_i,b_i]$ is the interval which bounds the root.
- $\hat c_i=\dfrac{a_if(b_i)-b_if(a_i)}{f(b_i)-f(a_i)}$ is the estimated next root from the secant approximation.
- $c_i=\dfrac{w_i\hat c_i+a_i+b_i}{w_i+2}$ is the next bound used, where $w_i$ is a weight.

Note that as $w\to\infty$, $c\to\hat c$, and as $w\to0$, $c\to\dfrac{a+b}2$, so we get a sort of continuum between the bisection and regula falsi methods.

This differs from the Illinois type methods mentioned in the link above in that we are adjusting an average of $a,b,c$ opposed to adjusting an averaging of $f(a)$ and $f(b)$, so this method can depend on the function less, making it closer to the bisection method.

The exact choice of $w$ can vary, though I've found it works reasonably well with something like

$$w_{i+1}=\begin{cases}w_i^2,&f(c_i)f(c_{i-1})<0\\w_i^{3/4},&f(c_i)f(c_{i-1})>0\end{cases}$$

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##xVhLT@NIEL77V/QGMUqMbWwnaGcQsNLe5jCX1Uh7SExkFhssjBO127O9YvLb2arqbrsdwmMCAUjsflbVV/VVP8Kbi//ua3GZLWt2yqLMj0IHqreprIVuC0NnyYtKFNUVVPO0rLP7i6LO/hHFomKn/hnLPSZL@DYeU3OUQI9ZYmyhdw6DCdAoy0As5jlWG6w2ppo387q4qlDfVDYJO2Mh@4NF7JiF0AufZSNqNvjTmHE8aNtIxUzIcibwX3L9btTbLxdX8VA2vixHA1bkzGBTcvMFZ8rIomJREBiboQs6uTIIXyCCHQCAETtkcULd9FBG7F/OxH4QHeUPXvmA7bMpydRe48pz/rdUXAeWdcmadVrBBc/SG@yiUeyEXP7zJxgXpBe1qrvuuJsAQ3PuGo@ekAfxT0WAUy2DoJrmxmquLh3z7DsYxuzdUWk1q3hWN6WgJslXJhTDERR4JhpeMYOXOyvH@Tcrrq5FdjmH4KWV2JpCeanCYTEpIe5o2nSMomYKHp8vefYDSsoIKMRBj1J/a@MU0dlyURfbE2wmqKJ0bUE3Y2yuwtHaPI2ycRh6usFVryS4LSoapwlaQtCZDz5wc6LpkKpQ7g1CFnMtAssNDY2hqM3uU/9XqP5LdPdY16I1P5IB2lbXPWVjfvjZEFx760wT/HXJ0ssTT1ENTc835IunKGd37yRvirIsqkVRf0zC9LLkqzblvdbdtUR4EcG3ouyHrc7PEI6idAir1SNsf4aQFPunpu@EsDzFpTMt5@CljC8XZfqqI8M29H1ks24x/qVNZF9tE9@H1jsno1RR9qwEsjhRRyqJfMlHLuUQ0ALcNJTch13AxfQiZmITqXEl1mGgmh9THHDeMOd@DhsHbSUwCRLRx5Q8oNxsoF76Obf2HdB9CAJelMyI7bchJRMM/fQJnye0T0FegbE4SeEbdTn2YIujbY3o/@SUTYvGdjlN4h9N7H5gnkjhtQiSFZC20p64RfLS7KczWCmANBZZLea3mbheXKq9x035lUpJo2UKhxH9SUzzNEygp70pTGlWMrUGREl7EGtPgxuGxTjMbH4b@sfYv3mt6Y22ATqr@7Qs5639iePkhE2yO8quuqiGcgRECYOjlUNrTujQGhMFRw45AKa1y1jiKLd/B1@Bg9FlOHR1zHIUA4y35OFiIK4zRqb@gMVnCiEpVx5GplklA0fHpLPw5OSU2WHQuMBoWGAqvbhMcMExIGKXYGRyOfQryNyDyO81uXK0Mtew0FzAIihsgGY4ZYM76KGLSejeXbUaSci2CHB2TTDiOcAWDZ8HjUzvgE8jjx15cE1NbPjD6GAYIXA3BvA@lgEx1N4Q9N5dp2QlATJUFN7z@P0RS1ebgDCrN4QpAY0WfI7wdg1t4rHPj8RyMjIgVTQnu4nmpB9NaPgAAks/Gq0lLO5jbxtb0mInKmjYfZDHBPgLYP6yRmG3QgtagH5sEI63Zy/BAakfCSnK/MlOUEXhuT/50GDtEp18R4S/a5Aei48eAO3QRW3Oha@EtwNIncndwhEdykPc6435ZPzkZSeYvt1G3Hk8km94hLHV4pWq/VF3JtSPcTW2ml8cZsJc2QaOWIjUOsPZZ1D7XIRarbNqa9K08qMuXhgTVIT3sfUnXsTMvU3f6m5QeBgE6thvWTK9SdBvpqxP5vhVembVdxx8/JQuS9z9/w), a lot of test cases from [1] give similar convergence as the Illinois method, but in general this seems to be more reliable. There is also a table of the results at the end of the output.

1. Is there a name for this method?
2. Should I expect this to converge faster, slower, or roughly the same as the Illinois method? What is the order of convergence?

For the 2nd question, I believe it should be roughly the same, but better at handling multiple order roots and really bad initial bounds. <s>Some of the test cases suggest it may be slower in other situations though.</s> Overall it seems to be much more reliable.

---

[1]: Bus, Dekker: "*Two efficient algorithms with guaranteed convergence for finding a zero of a function*", 1975, ACM Trans. Num. Soft. (dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/355656.355659)[dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/355656.355659].

Comment: In the original paper of Dekker presenting the fzeroin method and variations, you can also find a collection of more or less nasty test examples for this class of methods, that is combinations of bracketing and using secant roots or similar.

Comment: Do you have a link or reference? ... it's probably in German isn't it.

Comment: Nah, it is not that old. Computer age. Bus, Dekker: *"Two efficient algorithms with guaranteed convergence for finding a zero of a function"*, 1975, ACM Trans. Num. Soft. https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/355656.355659

Comment: Other earlier references are in https://blogs.mathworks.com/cleve/2015/10/12/zeroin-part-1-dekkers-algorithm/, describing the migration of this algorithm from Algol to Matlab, and how to get from bisection to zeroin.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Thanks for the cases. :O It would appear to me that this performs better than the Illinois method, or at least much more reliably.